# How to add medic-injector to node.js app

Tags: node.js, inversion-of-control, code-injection

I've installed the medic-injector package and created an app/bootstrap.js file per the instructions found on medic-injector's github site at https://github.com/DrBenton/Medic-Injector-JS

How do we make sure the injectors are called once my app.js is fired up?  Anyone have any pointers?

Thanks in advance!

Tami

Answer (score 1):

After you create your injector and add mappings, you need to call the "triggerFunctionWithInjectedParams" method on your injector.

For example:

```
injector.triggerFunctionWithInjectedParams([function name that you want to call]);
```

See the api documentation for the injector class to see what methods it contains:
http://drbenton.github.com/Medic-Injector-JS/api/#!/api/sync.Injector

The basic usage of medic-injector is:

1. create an injector object
2. add mappings to injector
3. (remove mappings if desired, if mutating the injector)
4. use triggerFunctionWithInjectedParams to call the function with all of the mappings injected.

Comment: I created an app/bootstrap.js file exactly as outlined.  I then included it in my app.js via "bootstrap = require('./app/bootstrap')".  When I run "node app.js" an error is thrown inside of bootstrap.js on the line "var injector = new Injector()"...it is 'TypeError: object is not a function'.  Obviously this means node.js exports cannot find it.  I'm confused as to why this is not working.  Obviously I'm not setting things up correctly, however, with other node packages setup/usage is usually trivial.

Comment: Ok, I looked closer at the API link you gave me and refactored my bootstrap.js so that the first two lines do the following:
"var Injector = require('medic-injector').InjectorSync;  var injector = new Injector()"

It's not throwing any more errors...(I've been using Node.js for a week--newb me!).  However, how to I call a method with injected params as well as non-injected params?

Comment: Yes, I did and the app threw up again.  So this is my scenario: I have a method defined in another js file which I export via module.exports.  It's called "sendAlertViewEmail(emails, message, callback, mailOptions, smtpTransport)".  The following params should be injected: "mailOptions" and "smtpTransport".  I call "sendAlertViewEmail" from another js file.  Should I require('app/bootstrap') in the calling module and then use injector.triggerFunctionWithInjectedParams(sendAlertViaEmail) to actually call the method?

Comment: Yes, that is one way. You will have to have your injector visible to the module that makes the call so that it can use it.

Comment: The only case I want is to call it with a combination of both injected and non-injected params.  The "mailOptions" and "smtpTransport" params are both mappings created by my injector.  I need to call "sendAlertViaEmail(...)" with injected and non-injected params.

Comment: it looks like you do something like this:
    injector.triggerFunctionWithInjectedParams(func, [param1, param2, param3]);

In this case, the brackets are literal.  You pass the parameters as an array which the medic-injector will "apply" when it executes the function.

Comment: Thanks Brion.  It's not working however. :(  I've debugged into medic-injector.sync.js and it's not getting my function "context" (which is the array of params).  I really appreciate your help.  Perhaps I just bumped up into an edge-case and am not implementing correctly.  I'm thinking of refactoring my emailAlert module to be an object so I can just use the injector there via "injector.injectInto(this);"

Comment: Looking at it again, it looks like I was wrong on the ability to pass parameters.  The context sets the object for "this".  The triggerFunctionWithInjectedParams only applies the mapped values on the injector.  So it looks like you have to add mappings on the injector for each parameter that needs a value.  You can remove those mappings after the call if necessary for your program.

since you mention that you are new to node.js, I'll mention that injection and IoC is not mainstream node.js usage.  There may be easier ways to do what you want to do in node.js.

Comment: You are right.  On second thought I realized I was using it as a glorified dictionary.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17785/discussion-between-twright-and-brion-finlay)